# How to make sweet beer in india at home

Tags: fermentation, beer, equipment, beer-styles

Tell me recipe to make sweet beer . Beer are usually sour, hard taste . In india , how to make it at home ? please tell recipe

Comment: I havent tried anything ,because ingredients needed like malt are not available

Comment: Have you tried using sorghum extract instead of malt? It is used to make "gluten free" beer and is becoming popular in Europe. Alternatively why not try to make Ginger beer - it can be non alcoholic or with alcohol and it is very refreshing and can be made as sweet as you prefer.

Comment: I suppose a better comment would be to ask, "what brewing supplies are  available in your area"? If you have no malt you may well have no yeast and no hops and no sugar either and that might make brewing beer very difficult! In which case you could either travel to buy the ingredients, get them delivered, move to a major city or give up trying to brew beer...
Also do you have an example of a sweet beer that you are trying to brew - or even the name of a sour/hard tasting beer that you don't like. That may give an idea of the style of beer you want to make.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to say that, but **buy a brew kit online**. That way you will not need to worry about what's available, you will get what you need in one neat package. Pay for fastest shipping possible to get it still fresh.

If you succeed, great. We then can help you with ingredients substitution. If you fail, still good. Tell us what exactly you did and how exactly you failed and we will be able to help with that.

I usually encourage people to go all grain from the beginning, but if malted grain is not available and you have a history of failures, starting with something already partially made may be good way to find out what works for you, and to boost your morale.

Good luck!

Comment: Do you think it makes a difference to pay for fastest shipping? Aren't these kits already made and sit just on the shelf?

Comment: A kit is a good idea but no point it paying for express shipping. The kits will not deteriorate in a few months!. AG is quite a task for a new brewer and requires more kit to do usefully.

Comment: In hot weather yeast can deteriorate rather quickly, and shipping companies rarely respect storage temperature guidelines. Your choice. With history of failed brews I think staying safe is a good idea.

Comment: Makes sense for the yeast.

Comment: maybe order some extra yeast with the kit? Just in case....